# Laravel 5 / PyroCMS 'No hint path defined for [streams].'

Tags: php, laravel, pyrocms

I do not know what I do anymore, I've already searched in several places and none has helped me so far.

What happens is that, I installed PyroCMS on my localhost, and at the time of transferring to the server is giving this error, is it some configuration that is missing? what could it be?

```
[10-Nov-2016 15:25:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'No hint path defined for [streams].' in /home/sppraiascom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:112
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sppraiascom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(90): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->getNamespaceSegments('streams::errors...')
#1 /home/sppraiascom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(76): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findNamedPathView('streams::errors...')
#2 /home/sppraiascom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(174): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find('streams::errors...')
#3 /home/sppraiascom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(69): Illuminate\View\Factory->make('streams::errors...', Array)
#4 /home/sppraiascom/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Exception/ExceptionHandler.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory->view('streams::errors...', Array, 500)
#5 /home/sppraiascom/vendor/larave in /home/sppraiascom/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php on line 112
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  What worked for me was to use a MySQL user account that had localhost as the user's host in MySQL ('username@localhost' not 'username@%').